# Is the description of the Student badge wrong?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The description of the Student badge says: "Asked first question with at least one up vote".
When I look at [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056699/user1056699]), I notice this user has received upvotes for his first question, but no badge.
It seems to me that the upvote was [long enough ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1056699/user1056699?tab=reputation#page_1-view_time) that the badge script should have awarded him a badge.

So I guess it's because this user had a negative score. Should the description of the badge read "Asked first question with a score of at least 1"?

Comment: Phwe... he doesn't *deserve* a badge for questions of that quality :P

Comment: I did not think the questions showed research effort, so IMO they didn't deserve upvotes - let alone badges. Apparently somebody thought otherwise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258), the criterion is that the question have a score of 1.

Assuming that's accurate, that user's questions received downvotes such that the questions possibly never achieved a score of one.  (This is as you surmise.)

And if that's correct, then yes, the description of the Student badge is slightly inaccurate.

Answer (score 8):

After our deploy the new description will be:  Asked first question with score of 1 or more

Comment: It could be better. It appears to imply that you can get this badge only on the first question you asked. Why not simply say "Asked a question with score of 1 or more" ?

Comment: @Koper Good point, but your version might give the impression that you could get the badge multiple times. I don't have a better idea though.